# Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

```
error C2664: 'void add_log(char *,...)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [33]' to 'char *'

message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
```

I restarted my computer and now my project stopped being able to be built. I've looked everywhere that had the similar problems but can no longer build this project with any changes to the project.

Using -> ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)

Character Set -> Use Multi-Byte Character Set

I don't understand what happened in a span of a few minutes for this to just completely break my project when I was compiling multiple times this morning.

Comment: This has been forbidden for a long time. Compilers are/were however lenient on it. Your function should take a `const char*` instead of a `char*` if you want to pass it string literals.

Comment: String literals are const, so the parameter must be `const char *`. While you might persuade your compiler to accepet it (note that it mentions the flag, `/Zc:strictStrings`), it's better to fix your code.

Comment: Ok, I'm just wondering how this can happen out of the blue. I've already corrected it and everything is still working as intended.

Comment: Many a programmer has been bedeviled by functions attempting to modify the data in a string literal, so it was made illegal decades ago to stem the bleeding. But so much code already existed that allowed string literals to be passed to harmless-but-not-`const`-requiring functions that it's only recently become a hard error, as opposed to a warning, in many compilers. Check for compiler updates installed recently.

Comment: I think MSVC made this a hard error only if the `/std:c++20` flag (or before that flag existed `/std:c++latest`) is used (or alternatively `/permissive-`): https://godbolt.org/z/q5ddE5jMd.

Comment: @user17732522 I always set my projects for C++17, but after updating just now..I now notice VS2019 now has the C++20 available. Even setting the conformance mode does not allow it.

Comment: @MinseokKim The conformance mode is exactly what doesn't allow for it (conformance = conformance to the standard). It is what I am doing above with the `/permissive-` flag. It is default with C++20.

Comment: @MinseokKim Please create an answer to this question and accept it, so the question can be closed and serve as a reference for anyone searching.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, all I had to do was add a const before anything that I use a char* for.  This was used with VS2019 using std:c++17 and Multi-Byte Character Set.

**The original code**:

```
void add_log(char* format, ...)
```

**The new code**

```
void add_log(const char* format, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add /permissive to the C++ Command Line Options

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I'm working with an ancient SDK, so I can't just adopt modern practices. Thanks! =)